# How to provide placeholders for multiple rows in EXCEPT clause?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3-python

My goal is to, given a list of id's in Python, find id's not mapped to a row in an SQLite table. I'm trying to achieve this using the `EXCEPT` operator:

```sql
-- if the table currently stores id1 and id3 would only return id2
WITH cte(id) as VALUES ('id1'), ('id2'), ('id3')
SELECT * from cte EXCEPT SELECT id FROM some_table
```

I want to specify id's dynamically from a list. I'm able to format strings, hardcoding values:

```py
query = (
    "with cte(id) as " +
    f"(values {",".join(f"('{id}')" for id in ids)}) " +
    "select * from cte except select id from some_table"
    )
print(query)
res = cursor.execute(query)
```

This is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Instead placeholder syntax is preferred. [Python sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-placeholders-to-bind-values-in-sql-queries) show examples with `executemany` for `INSERT` operations, but how to apply that to a SELECT+EXCEPT single query (which must use `execute` and not `executemany`)? Alternatively, is there a better way to filter a list of inputs by those which aren't present in a table? Sample of my problem:

```py
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cursor = db.cursor()

#
# First create a table of video-id,video-title pairs
#

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS videos(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT)")
dummy_data = [
    ("vid1", "Video 1"),
    ("vid2", "Video 2"),
    ("vid3", "Video 3"),
]

# use executemany to insert multiple rows via placeholder VALUES
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO videos VALUES(?, ?)", dummy_data)
db.commit()

# sanity check that we see the expected videos
res = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM videos")
print(f"select* result: {res.fetchall()}")

#
# Next, given a set of video ids, find all of the ids not already stored in the DB
#

new_video_ids = ["vid1", "vid2", "vid5"] # vid1 and vid2 already exist in db. only vid5 should be returned
new_video_ids_str = ",".join(f"('{id}')" for id in new_video_ids)
print(new_video_ids_str)

# The following query uses python string formatting and is therefore vulnerable to SQL injection attacks
query = (
    "with cte(id) as " +
    f"(values {new_video_ids_str}) " +
    "select * from cte except select id from videos"
    )
print(query)
res = cursor.execute(query)
print(f"filter result: {res.fetchall()}")

# I'd like to use SQLite3 placeholder values but can't figure out the syntax. The following doesn't work.
# it fails since it's trying to all of the `new_video_ids` values as a single row rather than multiple rows.
#
# query = (
#     "with cte(id) as " +
#     "(values (?)) " +
#     "select * from cte except select id from videos"
#     )
# res = cursor.execute(query, new_video_ids)
# print(f"filter result: {res.fetchall()}")

db.close()
```

Comment: Just replace `{id}` with `?` in your original code *(to make a dynamically varying string of `VALUES (?), (?), etc, etc`)* and then pass `*ids` as the parameter?

Comment: That worked! I didn't consider still using string formatting to generate the list of placeholders in the string. Thanks. I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_video_ids = ["vid1", "vid2", "vid5"] # vid1 and vid2 already exist in db. only vid5 should be returned

new_video_ids_str = ",".join(
   ["(?)"] * len(new_video_ids)
)

print(new_video_ids_str)

query = (
    "with cte(id) as " +
    + f"(values {new_video_ids_str}) " +
    + "select * from cte except select id from videos"
    )

print(query)

res = cursor.execute(query, new_video_ids)

print(f"filter result: {res.fetchall()}")
```

Comment: this works though one follow up I forgot in my above comment is that I think you just pass `new_video_ids` and not `*new_video_ids` since cursor.execute expects the parameters to be packaged in some iterable value like a tuple or list and the `*` would separate them back out into separate params